# Image scaling on Windows Phone with Xamarin Forms

Tags: windows-phone, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project and am having issues with the scaling of images with Windows Phone.  [Windows and Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwVR7.png)

I'm using a Grid to display all of the icons, here is the code I used for 1 image button.

```
<Button Image="cam.png"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        BorderColor="Transparent"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        Clicked="OnTrafficClicked"/>
```

I've found a couple similar posts about this, but I don't understand how I would implement scaling on platform when there are multiple images.

I tried this, but am unable to run the program

```
<Image.Scale>
  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Scale"
              WinPhone="1.5" />
</Image.Scale>
```

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19525/image-source-with-onplatform-in-xaml

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47947/differences-with-scaling-between-the-platforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, in case anyone has this same issue this is what I did:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <OnPlatform x:Key="stdScaling" x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
      iOS="1.0"
      Android="1.0"
      WinPhone="2.5" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

then for the button, I put

```
Scale= "{StaticResource stdScaling}"
```